# Is there a way to use $match multiple times in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

events collection

```
device time        distance
id_1   3 mins ago  4
id_1   6 mins ago  4
id_1   1 day ago   4
id_1   8 mins ago  4
id_2   7 mins ago  4
id_2   8 mins ago  4
```

What I want to do is, select devices which pushed events alteast 5 mins ago and calculate distance for today's date

expected output i want, will be

```
device status  total_distance
id_1   active  12
```

Comment: did you write any query for it yet?

Comment: @AnveegSinha I tried. but either I can calculate distance for today's date for all devices or select active devices. I'm looking for a way to do both in single aggregation.

Comment: Please create a sample playground example here https://mongoplayground.net/, and share the link in the question along with the query that you have tried.

Comment: Please add your attempted query in the question

Comment: Yes, you can use `$match` multiple times. But your question would require more details to give an answer.